Нужна ли запятая перед "протяжённостью"?
Наше ограждение представляет собой забор(?) протяжённостью 100 метров.

Правильно:
Наше ограждение представляет собой забор протяжённостью 100 метров.
Пояснение

Несогласованное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного, в данном  предложении не обособляется, так как указывает на основной (постоянный) признак предмета.

Тема регулируется правилам ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 53, где говорится о факультативном обособлении таких определений:
Если же определяемое имя не имеет других (согласованных) 
определений, то обособление несогласованных определений 
факультативно. В таком случае обособлению способствует 
необходимость указания на вполне конкретные, частные 
признаки предмета или признаки временно́го характера, 
приписываемые предмету в данный момент: Крошки, размером с 
конопляное зерно, должны быть тщательно подобраны (Вороб.); 
Доктор, со шпагою в руке, выбежал в спальню (Тын.). Ср., 
однако: Продавец в чистом белом халате и синей шапочке 
обслуживал... клиента (Булг.).
При обозначении постоянных признаков определение не 
обособляется: На табуретках с золочеными ножками сидел целый 
ряд дам (Булг.).


Но несогласованное определение обособляется, если обозначаетдополнительный, а не основной признак предмета в данном сообщении.

Забор, протяжённостью 100 метров, был построен за несколько дней.

Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, а разве нельзя ваше предложение без запятых написать? Забор протяжённостью 100 метров был построен за несколько дней.

Можно.  По структуре и интонации такое предложение проходит, оно не будет перегруженным. Но выбор варианта зависит от контекста. Если нам было важно подчеркнуть длину забора, то сочетание войдет в основную структуру и не будет обособляться. А обособляется в том случае, если это по тексту добавочная информация, а основное содержание - за несколько дней.  //Здесь еще  интересно, как меняется тема и рема в простом предложении –  как раз сейчас обсуждаем актуальное членение, где я говорю о связи его с обособлением. Оба решения возможны, если допустимы два варианта деления, как здесь.
